# using thresholds to delete outliers

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.11

I have a dataset, with a few columns,  when I wanted to delete the outliers using z-score I initiated low and high thresholds for it as followed:

```
low = df[columns].quantile(0.003)
high = df[columns].quantile(0.997)
```

then used the following code to delete the outliers:

```
df = df[(df[columns]>low).any(axis=1)]
df = df[(df[columns]<high).any(axis=1)]
```

however it didn't delete anything, so I changed it to this:

```
df = df[~(df[columns]<low).any(axis=1)]
df = df[~(df[columns]>high).any(axis=1)]
```

This one worked, and deleted the outliers.

I expected both work the same, I just don't understand why the first one doesn't work. can someone please explain to me what makes the first one don't work and the second work? what is the difference anyway?

Comment: Do you have NaNs? Please provide an example of your data. Also you're not doing the same operation, `(df[columns]>low).any(axis=1)` is equivalent to `~(df[columns]<low).all(axis=1)`  ([DeMorgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws))

Comment: - The first method selects rows where ANY column is above the low threshold and then, from that result, selects rows where ANY column is below the high threshold. This approach doesn't filter out the outliers effectively.

- The second method, however, discards rows where ANY column is below the low threshold or ANY column is above the high threshold. This approach effectively removes the outliers. `the first method includes more rows while the second method excludes more, which is why the latter is effective at removing outliers.`

Answer (score 0):

`(df[columns]>low).any(axis=1)` and `~(df[columns]<low).any(axis=1)` are not the same operation.

If you reverse and negate the condition, you should swap ANY/ALL according to [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) (ANY is equivalent to the boolean OR, and ALL to AND).

In your case, since `~(df[columns]<low).any(axis=1)` is giving the correct output you should have used **ALL**:

```
(df[columns]>low).all(axis=1)
```

Also, keep in mind the role of NaNs, if you have NaNs then both operations `NaN>low` and `NaN<low` will give the same `False`. Thus `~(NaN<low)` is not the same as `(NaN>low)`.

Finally, don't forget that the opposite of `>` is `<=`.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                   [1, 2, 1, 2],
                   [3, 4, 3, 4]
                  ])

np.array_equal((df>2).any(axis=1), ~(df<=2).all(axis=1))

# True
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally got it. I followed your instruction and it's working as well. both "all" and "<=" were my errors in the code. Thanks for the help.